# git add all gitted subdirectories

Tags: git, github, push

I'm creating putting all my projects on a folder and I make in this folder

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m"init"
```

After that, I create a new git repository in github and I copied like usually commands to add the repository, but When I pushed, I found that the content of all my projects haven't been pushed, but the not gitted directories are pushed correctly, I want to push all my gitted projects, how can I do ?

Comment: Are you attempting to add multiple git projects into a single folder and committing that to Github?

Comment: @Tyler: Yes, I'm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some git repositories inside a git repository (e.g : "gitted subfolders" inside your parent folder), the default behavior of git is to ignore these subrepositories when you run `git add` from the parent repository.

You will need to track each of your gitted directory in its own dedicated repository on github.

Answer (score 1):

okay, let's be clear here. executing a `git init` makes the current directory that you have cd'd in, a git project. 
once your have executed a git init, you can start tracking that directory into a git repository! 
in your case, when you are trying to track all your projects in git, you will need to `cd` into each of those directories where your projects are using:

```
 cd path_to_your_project/
```

you will need to convert them to a git project by executing

```
 git init
```

then, you will have to add all the untracked files using:

```
 git add --all
```

then, you need to make you first commit:

```
git commit -m "my first commit"
```

once you have comited your changes, you can start tracking the project remotely by giving it an origin and pushing your changes to master (example assumes repo on github):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<git_user_name>/<repo_name>
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: So you want to say that I have to push every project on an appropriate repository ? in my root file I cleaned my git status by navigating in every project and commiting changes but when I push the gitted project appears as inaccessible folders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not add the new files to your staging. See what changes are stages with `git status` and stage all files in your repo with `git add -A`. Then commit and push your changes to the remote repo.

Also you might want to check how you set up your remote repo. With `git remote add origin remote repository URL` you link your local repo to your remote GitHub repo. With `git push -u origin master` you should be able to push your changes to GitHub (which you named origin)

Comment: No I've done git status and I navigate to all directory and I've commited all changes until the git status become clean, and the push succeed but my gitted projects were been pushed as inaccessible folders.